# jquery multiple attribute selector problem

Tags: jquery

I've a little question, why this simple code does not work?

html:

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a">
<input type="text" name="ab" id="ab">
<input type="text" name="b" id="b">
<input type="text" name="c" id="c">
<input type="text" name="d" id="d">
```

js:

```
$("[name^='a'][name='c']").css("background-color", "red");
```

Thanks in advance, ciao h.

Comment: what do you mean with _does not work_ ?

Answer (score 9):

You need to add comma to your selector:

```
$("[name^='a'],[name='c']").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering, I followed jquery documentation an there example not use comma :-(

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a comma between expressions

$("[name^='a'],[name='c']").css("background-color", "red");

Answer (score 2):

use `comma` to seperate your selectors

```
$("input[name^='a'],[name='c']").css("background-color", "red");
```